# C# DROPBOX API modify 10000 file limit

Tags: c#, dropnet

I'm working with dropbox: upload, delete, copy,..etc through DropNet API. So the problem is I can't access any folder that has over 10000 files. How can I improve it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DropBox' REST API limits file access to 10,000 files per folder.

So I'm afraid there's really nothing you can do, except fragment your folder into subfolders and limit them to <= 10,000 files each.

Answer (score 1):

file_limit Default is 10,000 (max is 25,000). When listing a folder, the service won't report listings containing more than the specified amount of files and will instead respond with a 406 (Not Acceptable) status response.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata